# Laravel Sail Share gives 404 or ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

Trying to use the `Sail Share` command with Laravel Sail, but it's not working. I've tried removing the `beyondcodegmbh/expose-server` image as recommended [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues).

It installs and everything seems to be working fine. I can get to the expose dashboard where you can follow the requests, but trying to use the expose http url without the port gives me a 404, and the url with the port just spins forever and never does anything. If I click the https link that comes up in the CLI I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. Sail 8.1. Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57.

My use case is that I'm trying to interact with an external API while doing my local development, and the API requires an HTTPS redirect url, so obviously I have to have SSL and the ability to expose the URL.

If there's another way to accomplish this without using expose, please let me know. Currently also looking into using Caddy, based on some other resources I've found.

**UPDATE**

I've tried changing my docker-compose.yml file with the following:

```
expose:
        image: beyondcodegmbh/expose-server:latest
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        ports:
          - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
          port: ${APP_PORT}
          domain: ${APP_URL}
          username: 'admin'
          password: 'admin'
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./database/expose.db:/root/.expose
```

which I got from [this link](https://github.com/beyondcode/expose/pull/293/commits/79855fcf9cfa91934c8121a32fb8ee257275840e), but it's still not working. I'm using port 80 in the APP_URL in my .env file, and then I put 8080 for the expose port, I'm not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, it appears to be a known limitation.
The https links generated from `sail share` do not work.
See [this ticket](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/216#issuecomment-1185743714)